# Linking java class methods using Rascal Shell

Tags: rascal

I am unable to link java classes when using the rascal shell interpreter. This the error message that I receive:

> unexpected error: Cannot link method org.my.MyClass because: class not found

Using Eclipse's rascal shell works. Tried with both stable (0.8.0.201510190912) and unstable (0.8.0.201606061752) versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running the release jar using `java -jar rascal-<version>.jar`, then the only safe way I know how is to pack your Rascal sources and the necessary class files into the jar with the rest of Rascal. You might also try and extend the java classpath with the `-cp` option to `java`.

Comment: I made it work without compiling everything by just listing all jars that I need in -cp including `rascal-shell-unstable.jar`:
`java -cp /path/to/rascal.jar:my_lib.jar:. org.rascalmpl.shell.RascalShell`

Since `-jar` option will ignore `-cp` classpaths. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Thanks for the report!